# How to count bath: Roman baths

Tags: phrase-meaning, articles

I saw some sentences where both "Bath" and "the Roman Baths" are used to indicate Roman baths.
See the left-upper section of this site: [Stonehenge tickets and tours](https://tickets.london/news/stonehenge-tickets-and-tours/3805?_ga=2.85421593.1604720434.1643855818-1473778383.1643855818).

How can I understand about that?  Does "Bath" mean one bath, and "the Roman baths" several ones?

Comment: bath is singular, baths is plural

Comment: @DialFrost Thank you so much for your answer!  In the title of a tour it says "Bath," and in the further explanations it says "the Roman Baths." So, at the title the writer imagined one bath, and imagined several ones later?

Comment: Do you have an online copy that I can see for this? (so I answer your question better)

Comment: @DialFrost Thank you so much for your help!  Another person answered me while I was typing you a question, and I understand why there were bath and baths now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: "In the title of a tour it says "Bath,""  **???** what tour.  You haven't mentioned any tour.  Please remember we can't read your mind.  You **must** tell us the source of the quote.  The best way is to add a URL in your question.

Comment: I suspect "Bath" might be the name of the city.  Or it might not. So the accepted answer might be right or it might be not.

Comment: @JamesK I see! Thank you, I will add a URL.

Comment: But, damn!  London-Windsor-Stonehenge-Bath-London in one day.  That has to be at least 6 hours on a coach, even if the traffic is kind. That really leaves you with maybe 30 minutes at each attraction!  Hell-of-a-lot of money to sit in a queue on the A303 all day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you seem to refer to is:

> Explore beautiful Bath with a walking tour and visit the famous Roman Baths and Pump Rooms.

In this line, ["Bath" is the name of a city.](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Bath/)

[The "Roman Baths"](https://goo.gl/maps/WKBweiwdzzxkgMR89) is the name of a collection of 18th century bathhouses in the city, built around a hot spring, on the site of an ancient Roman *balneum*. There's also a museum and other attractions. You can't actually take a bath here anymore!

These are both proper nouns, though the second is plural.  They refer to specific places.

Comment: The 'bathhouses' date from the 18th century onwards, so not really 'ancient' by UK standards. The hot springs are still there.

Comment: Okay, but it's on the site of the roman baths

Comment: The fact that "Bath" is capitalized is another giveaway that it means the city and not just any old bath.  If it were talking about the baths in Bath, it'd be all lower-case in addition to be plural, unless you preface it by stating "the Roman Baths", which is the name of a specific location, but that would never be singular.  You could say "a Roman bath" to talk about just one bath there, or "the Roman Baths" to refer to the whole place.  ("Roman" of course should always be capitalized.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - What makes this particularly confusing is that *Roman Baths* is also capitalized.  The name of the city is capitalized and so is the name of the *baths*.  I might think *Roman Baths* is also the name of a city.

Answer (score 2):

"Bath" is singular, "baths" is plural.

Although, in the context of a Roman bath, "bath" could mean a single *bath house*, which could contain multiple individual pools. I think either is correct in that context.

Comment: This is irrelevant. When _bath_ is a common noun, it needs an article in the singular. Here, as James K says, it's the name of a city.

Comment: To be fair, when Quinn wrote this answer, it wasn't clear what the OP was talking about, and this did answer the question as it was written before the OP edited it.